@Validated and @Valid in Spring Controllers work different with return type
I have a Spring Boot 3 project with Validation dependency added.
There is POJO - Human:
@Data
public class Human {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String email;
}

And there is controller with validation that works as expected:
It's validating received Human object.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stub")
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/exampleUpdate")
    public Human getExampleUpdate(@Valid @RequestBody Human human) {
        System.out.println("Updat Validated Successfully");
        return human;
    }
}

I am passing in this controller a request from a postman:
postman request
And if i change @Valid on @Validated and back on method parameter i always get same result as response:
postman response
But here is coming my problem with this controller:
I've changed request validation to response validation and i get confusing results.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stub")
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/exampleUpdate")
    @Valid
    public Human getExampleUpdate(@RequestBody Human human) {
        System.out.println("Update Validated Successfully");
        return human;
    }
}

Request in postman is the same.
But this time i receive different response on @Valid:
postman response
And if i change @Valid on @Validated - validation is gone. It's just returning me object with blank field like it's fine:
postman response
Why does Spring exhibit such confusing and inconsistent behavior?
I expected that when validating a returned object, the validation behavior would be similar to the behavior when receiving an object. That is, you can replace @Valid with @Validated, and the behavior would not change.

You did read the javadoc didn't you?

This isn't confusing or inconsistent.  When @Valid is used on the input it should be accompanied by a BindingResult, which should be a parameter to your controller method.  When it's used on the response, you're just going to get the BindingResult as the response.  It doesn't make any sense to use it on the response, you are building the response so you should not be returning something that is invalid to begin with.

@lane.maxwell
There is point of using it on response. In case of complex logic in application it may be useful as final check before giving a response.

@M.Deinum
Yes, I read it back then and reread it now, carefully. It says that ‘for example’ it can be used with Spring MVC handler methods arguments. Then, it talks about using it on classes and methods.
Am I correct in understanding that using this annotation on method parameters is only possible within the context of Spring MVC?
And the other usages (on classes and methods) behave somewhat differently. On a class, it enables method-level validation, and on a method, it specifies validation groups for that particular method.

You did read this part Applying this annotation at the method level allows for overriding the validation groups for a specific method but does not serve as a pointcut. So yes on methods / return values it is only for specifying the validation groups (you should not use it on a class when it is an @[Rest]Controller as that serves a different purpose).

@M.Deinum
Could you please explain why it is not recommended to use Validated on Controller classes? I assume there is some sort of conflict in the validation mechanisms?

The error handling is different the @Validated on classes is intended for service layers to handle validation, which don't have that build in. Validation for Spring MVC is build into the MVC part.

@M.Deinum Thanks a lot! That’s really helpful!

Why does Spring exhibit such confusing and inconsistent behavior?
It is not really confusing. Although response validation is quite rare, the behavior is quite reasonable.
When you are validating the request, which is provided by client. HTTP 400 BadRequest is best to describe the invalid input. So client could fix the request and resend.
But when you are validating the response, which is created by the server, it does not really make sense to return 400, as the response is from the server. It is actually an server error(that why it return 500 Internal Server Error). There is no way client can fix the error.

Thank you for the clarification, it actually makes sense! This point is clear now. But honestly, I was more interested in why Valid and Validated behave almost identically in one place (if no groups are specified), but in another case Valid works, and Validated does not.
From the explanations of other users and the documentation, I suppose that it is working as it is supposed to. However, it’s really confusing why the behavior is different on method parameters and on methods themselves. That doesn’t feel right.
